# R Shiny: downloadButton styling and icon

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to change the icon or at least control the padding of the downloadButton in Shiny?

I've already tried setting the class:

```
downloadButton("html_link", label = NULL, class = "download_this")
```

Then in CSS:

```
.download_this{
    height:40px;
    width:57px;
    color:blue;
    padding-top: 3 !important;
}
```

This changes the size and color, however for some reason the padding doesn't work on the icon and it appears too high on the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like an error in your `.css` , `css padding` generates space around content, `3` means nothing to **css**, try:

```
padding-top: 3px
```

Comment: I've tried padding-top: 3px and changed the values to 0px, 10px, 100px with and without '!important' and still nothing has changed.

Comment: Yes, that does work - I was rerunning the app without pressing stop, it seems doing that doesn't reload the css file and so I didn't see the change.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.